Anime about humans fighting aliens on another planet
I'm looking for an old anime, probably from the 1980s or early 1990s, where humans are fighting against aliens on another planet, possibly on Mars (definitely a desert planet).
The humans were piloting some kind of vehicles (unsure if tanks or robots) and in the anime I've seen, they planned to attack a giant moving fortress that, in the German translation, was called "hell".
Some more things I remembered: I believe the anime had a military setting and the protagonists were a group of males. The giant moving fortress may have warped around (instead of rolling on tracks) and may have been difficult to pinpoint for an attack.
In the anime I'm looking for, humans were in a war, down to a few soldiers that had mostly lost hope, no funny scenes, no joking, no living plant in the entire movie (probably)
Can anyone think of an anime that fits the description?

Now and Then, Here and There contains an enemy moving "fortress" called Hellywood. The anime "follows a young boy named Shuzo "Shu" Matsutani who, in an attempt to save an unknown girl, is transported to another world which is possibly the Earth in the far future. The world is desolate and militarized, and water is a scarce commodity." It's decidedly dark, containing elements of slavery, abuse, and rape.

Give Terra Formers a try, as it relates to what you want

@EdChum users of the stackexchange network are welcomed to post their question to whatever site they think best suits them.  it is generally discouraged to double-post a question - ie post the same question on two separate sites.  if the user wanted to migrate the question that is a potential solution, but this question is so old now it's probably not an option anymore

@DForck42 I didn't think that multi-site posting was against the rules, I thought that so long as the question was on-topic for both sites then it could be posted if there was some overlap as opposed to a situation where a question is more suited or really only on-topic for a specific site

@EdChum there's a lot of literature over the SE network about this, but here's a solid one from meta.se: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/161679

@EdChum no problem.  it's also ACTIVELY discouraged to try and "steal" away users from other sites when content overlaps.  ie, Movies&TV, SFF, LIT, Anime, etc.

I think this one could be it, Kami Utsu Akaki Kouya Ni
aka, Big Wars. 


It was aired in 1993, humans are fighting aliens (or the "gods"), it happens in Mars which is a desert planet, humans pilot large amphibious cruisers/tank vehicles (main combat doesn't happen until minute 35).
Also the main alien enemy carrier is called "Hell", and is always enveloped in a sand storm, and very difficult to detect. Cannot think of a better match to the description in the question. 
Hope it helps.
Cheers

can edit your answer to explain why you think this is the one? In case the link to the video dies... How does the plot matches what's being asked?

we also don't want to have to watch the whole movie just to find out that it's the wrong one

edited my answer, I think it explains better now

Yes, that's it! This is the movie I've been looking for! Thank you very much for digging up this old question :)

I think you might be talking about Macross also known as Robotech.





Yeah, but the "moving fortress" in the Macross saga belongs to the humans. I can see a case for the second saga of Robotech (Southern Cross) where humans were in another planet (in the original series at least) fighting against an alien fortress but the protagonist is a woman, which contradicts the OP's claim of them being "a group of males".
